# how can I treat different apostrophe formats the same way in a js regex?

Tags: javascript

I need the ability to evaluate the following strings as equal even though the apostrophe format is different between the strings:

- Hickman’s
- Hickman's

Can you recommend a good way for me to do this in js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const
  first = 'Hickman’s',
  second = "Hickman's",
  isEquals = !first.localeCompare(second, 'en', { ignorePunctuation: true });

console.log(isEquals);
```